# Form Validation with jquery - Highlight Error Field

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, highlight

I need some help with my jquery validation form. I managed to get everything to work except for the highlight of the error text box part. I need the following tho happen:

Whenever an rule get broken for a field, that field must have a yellow background color applied to it for 3 seconds; then it changes back to white.
Can someone please help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js">    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#form1").validate({ 



        rules: { 
          name: {
                  required: true,
                  minlength: 3
                },

          date: {
                  date:true
                },

          email: {// compound rule 
            required: true, 
            email: true 
                 }, 
        url: { 
          url: true 
        },


        }, 
        messages:
        { 
          name: {
          minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required.")
                }
        }




      }); 
    }); 
  </script> 


<style type="text/css"> 
    * { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; } 
    .submit { margin-left: 125px; margin-top: 10px;} 
    .label { display: block; float: left; width: 120px; text-align: right; margin-right: 5px; } 
    .form-row { padding: 5px 0; clear: both; width: 700px; } 
    label.error { width: 250px; display: block; float: left; color: red; padding-left: 10px; } 
    input[type=text], textarea { width: 250px; float: left; } 
    textarea { height: 50px; } 
</style> 

</head>
 <body>
      <form id="form1" method="post" action=""> 
        <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Name *</span><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
            <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Birthdate </span><input type="text" name="date" /></div>
            <div class="form-row"><span class="label">E-Mail *</span><input type="text" name="email" /></div>
            <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Home page</span><input type="text" name="url" /></div> 

          <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried to plug this in but just can't get it to work:

```
$(".selector").validate({
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
  $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
                .addClass(errorClass);
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
 $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
 $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
                .removeClass(errorClass);
}
});
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, 
that is the part I am struggling with. The "I tried to plug this is (above)" is what I found, but I am not sure how to plug it into my code.

Comment: But the above code doesn't come close to doing what you want, so I don't understand why you tried to plug it in. You need to do something with `setTimeout()` to do something 3 seconds later.

Comment: I Only tried to use that code cause it was in the jquery "validations".

Comment: Would you know how to go about achieving something like this with setTimeout?

Comment: What is `$(".selector")` supposed to be?  You **must** put `highlight` and `unhighlight` _inside_ of your original `$("#form1").validate()` function if it supposed to be for `#form1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will do it:

```
$("#form1").validate({
   ...
   highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
      $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
                     .addClass(errorClass);
      setTimeout(function() {
          $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
          $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
                         .removeClass(errorClass);
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: One more question...
can i plug this in right under the messages section..?

Comment: This is not correct, `$(".selector").validate()`, when his form is called `#form1`.  Custom `highlight` and `unhighlight` callbacks **must** go inside of the _initial_ `$("#form1").validate()` if they're intended for that form.

Comment: Your code also has some syntax issues, missing and unclosed braces, etc.

Comment: I've added the missing parens and braces. I think you should be able to insert this stuff before or after your other validation options.